# Issue getting KubeDNS to work

Tags: kubernetes, kube-dns, fedora-25

So I'm not sure how to proceed with troubleshooting, but I've been at it all day and searched high and low.

I'm unable to get the KubeDNS pod to work.  I'm deploying on Fedora 25 installed on bare metal.  I currently only have a single box in the cluster, with kubelet running on the master.  I am not running kubelet or the other Kubernetes services in containers.

When I try to run a DNS lookup inside the kubedns container on the kubernetes.default service (`nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1` and `nslookup kubernetes.default.svc.cluster.local 127.0.0.1:10053`) it fails.

What I've eventually found in the kube-apiserver log are messages like the following, lined up time-wise when I've tried to do the lookups:

`kube-apiserver[20876]: E0315 01:09:16.134237   20876 proxy.go:193] Error proxying data from client to backend: write tcp 192.168.1.203:33074->192.168.1.203:10250: write: broken pipe`

The service and replicationcontroller configs I'm using are from https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/deploy-addons.html#deploy-the-dns-add-on, with the `clusterIP` setting obviously changed to match my environment.

I'm not really sure where else to look in terms of troubleshooting, so any help is appreciated.  I'll post up whatever configs are useful, but figured it would be less than useless for me to guess about which configs those would be.

Comment: What Pod Networking are you using? Do you have connectivity to all pods?

Comment: I'm using Flannel for my networking.  I ran through the guide here - https://kubernetes.io/docs/getting-started-guides/fedora/fedora_manual_config/ - when setting it up, with adjustments for my own naming conventions and to have the master and one node on the same box.

I do not have connectivity to other pods, checked with ping.

Comment: My only idea, after **two** days of troubleshooting, stems from these log messages:

`kube-apiserver[27115]: I0315 18:40:06.628204   27115 logs.go:41] http: TLS handshake error from 172.16.40.7:47094: remote error: tls: bad certificate`


From what it sounds like, kube-dns can't authenticate with kube-apiserver.  However, I can find **zero documentation whatsoever** on how to give kube-dns a token, secret, or anything else to authenticate to kube-apiserver.

Comment: As you seem to be using https, you may want to try mounting a kubeconfig file in the container, and then pass it as parameter to the kubedns command. This fixed my SSL errors, although my kubedns is version is newer than the one in the page that you linked. This kubeconfig should contain the API server url/ip and some credentials.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up fixing this with some trial and error.

The problem, having followed the bare metal node setup guide for Fedora, was that I didn't have TLS configured for kube-apiserver.

These options were all required (having fixed it quite a long time ago, I don't remember which ones were missing):

- --service-account-key-file
- --tls-cert-file
- --tls-private-key-file
- --client-ca-file